# Замыкания. Почему в этом случае удаляется lexical environment родительской функции?

Tags: javascript, функции, переменные, сборщик-мусора, замыкания

Цитата с [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/closure#sborka-musora)

> В следующем коде, после того как g станет недоступным, лексическое окружение функции (и, соответственно, value) будет удалено из памяти:

```js
function f() {
    let value = 123;
    function g() {
        alert(value);
    }
    return g;
}
let g = f(); // пока g существует, соответствующее лексическое окружение существует 
g = null; // ...а теперь память очищается
```

Я не понимаю почему лексическое окружение родительской функции будет удалено из памяти. **Ведь мы по сути только очистили переменную `g` и сказали, что там ничего нет - `g = null`. Сама же вложенная функция осталась, ее никто не удалял.**

Разве вложенная функция не будет всегда хранить ссылку на родительскую ф-цию (даже без вызова) просто потому что код вложенной функции есть внутри? Типа браузер видит ф-цию, потом видит внутри этой функции еще одну вложенную ф-цию и думает: *"Ага, так как внутри функции есть еще одна - вложенная функция (пусть даже без вызова), лексическое окружение родительской функции удаляться уже не будет."*

Как это происходит? Почему переприсвоение переменной, в которой лежит вложенная функция, удаляет лексическое окружение родительской функции `f`?

Comment: Если человека убили, то он уже не может у себя хранить ключи, кошелёк и ходить на работу

Comment: По факту `g = null`, это сравнимо этому самому "убить"

Answer (score 0):

По факту это работает так, что контекст функции f каждый раз пересоздается заново при каждом запуске функции. Поэтому у вас внутри функции f нет никакой хранящейся постоянной функции g, она будет создана каждый раз заново во время запуска.

```js
function f() {
    function g() {}
    return g;
}

// false - это разные функции g, а не одна и та же
console.log(f() == f());
```

Пока вы храните ссылку на g она будет существовать, а она хранит ссылку на value в свою очередь и тоже будет существовать. Но как только вы потеряете эти ссылки, то обратиться к g уже никогда не сможете, ведь вызов f вернет совершенно новую функцию. Ну а мертвые ссылки подлежат удалению и они вам больше не к чему.